# Compile Cygwin project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, cygwin

I have a c++ Project that was compiled with the cygwin toolchain, now I want to use Eclipse to compile and test it. 
If I create a project (cygwin toolchain is set in the options) I get the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'. 7wWin       line 0  C/C++ Problem
```

In Cygwin I use:

```
cd $BUILDDIR
make
make install
```

Can Eclipse create it's own makefile? And how to setup that. 
Better would be a good tutorial how to compile a Cygwin c++ project with Eclipse.

Comment: please change the spelling error in the question name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following pages:

- http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/courses/fall2007/csc406/Handouts/eclipseTutorial.pdf
- http://wikimix.blogspot.com/2006/11/using-eclipse-as-c-development_05.html
- http://www.benjaminarai.com/benjamin_arai/index.php?display=/eclipsecygwingcc.php