# Compiling google test framework with Mingw compiler

Tags: windows, qt, mingw, googletest

I have a Qt project and i wanted to use google tests framework [GoogleTestFramework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) in order to do google test. The framework compiled fine on Linux.

I have managed to compile the libraries on windows, using tips provided in the following link: 
[Installing Gtest without pthreads](http://code.google.com/p/tonatiuh/wiki/InstallingGoogleTestForWindows)

The following advice do not let me compile the libraries, because of errors due to pthreads:
[Sackoverflow compiling with MSYS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248237/how-to-compile-googletest-on-windows-using-mingw-with-msys)

I have :

- GNU Make 3.81 for make.exe
- GNU Make 3.82 for mingw32-make
- CMake 2.8.7
- QT 4.7.4
- Qt MingW gcc v 4.4.0

When i try to compile my test projet, i get an error saying:
    undefined reference to '__chkstk_ms'
    File not found: gtest-all.cc

Here is my qmake project code (I have semplified the code).

```
QT       += core gui

DEPENDPATH += . headers src ../FastTrans/headers ../FastTrans/src ../FastTrans/forms      C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/zakharan/gtest-1.6.0/include
INCLUDEPATH += . headers src ../FastTrans/headers ../FastTrans/src ../FastTrans/forms     C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/zakharan/gtest-1.6.0/include

TARGET = tstall
#CONFIG   += console
#CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

HEADERS += ../FastTrans/headers/shortcutsactionsitem.h \
../FastTrans/headers/shortcutsactionsmodel.h \
../FastTrans/headers/isavesettings.h

SOURCES += ../FastTrans/src/shortcutsactionsitem.cpp \
../FastTrans/src/shortcutsactionsmodel.cpp \
../FastTrans/src/isavesettings.cpp \
src/tstshortcutsactionsitem.cpp \
src/tstshortcutsactionmodel.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/

win32: LIBS += C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/zakharan/gtest-1.6.0/mybuid/libgtest.a
win32: LIBS += C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/zakharan/gtest-1.6.0/mybuid/libgtest_main.a
```

Comment: Just wondering if there is an advantage to compiling it with MingW over Cygwing.

Comment: As far as i understand Cygwing it is not a compiler. In other words will not been able to compile my app with it so it works in windows.

Comment: Cygwin GCC compiles code for real, but it uses a POSIX<->WinAPI adaptation layer in form of a library file, which slows the resulting program down a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Google recommends the following for [compiling in Windows](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/README):

```
### Windows Requirements ###

  * Microsoft Visual C++ 7.1 or newer

### Cygwin Requirements ###

  * Cygwin 1.5.25-14 or newer
```

I've heard of some people using MingW for compiling this.  Supposedly compiling with MingW can be a little faster because there doesn't need to be a comparability layer between the OS and the application.

But, since this is just for dev testing purposes Cygwin should suffice.  Just download the version that Google recommends.

---

**See Also:**

[Compile Cygwin project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069085/256854)

[How Cygwin compares to MingW for porting Linux applications to Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw#Comparison_with_Cygwin)

Comment: However i am not sure it will be easy to compile my qt project with Cygwin.